# Interaction between covariate and 2-level within-subjects factor is of research interest. How to test

Tags: interaction, ancova

I'm interested in interpreting the interaction between a continuous variable (C) with a dichotomous within-persons factor (A) on a continuous DV (DV). What is the best overall test of this? Would it be appropriate to interpret the CxA interaction as this effect within an ANCOVA, even though it violates the assumptions of the ANCOVA (homogeneity of regression slopes). My preference would not be to "bin" the continuous covariate for this analysis. Could HLM simply be used with only two level-1 observations?

Comment: Do you have 2 level one observations? Or two observations per person? This sounds like a cross-level (slopes as outcomes) model in HLM, to me.

Comment: Two level-1 observations, with a large N for level 2. So, in this case the covariate is level-2 (person) and the categorical variable (A) is within person.

Comment: I would call that two level 1 observations per level 2 unit. Not two level 1 observations.